# How to show a image banner with good quality?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a size like width 300 and height 150,

So if I containt then the height and with are equal. So I stretch the image now, but it does not show good its look werid.

How can I show it with a good looking ?

€:
Code:

```
<Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={s.adsImage} resizeMode='stretch' />

css:
  adsImage: {
    height: 175, 
    width: width * 0.9
  }
```

Comment: Please include your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Agree with @sean-7777, Can you post the code block where you having the issue?